# Bitwise NOT operator returning unexpected and negative value?

Tags: c++, c, binary, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to get the value of an integer using Bitwise NOT, but i'm not getting  what i expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i = 16;
    int j = ~i;
    printf("%d", j);
    return 0;
}
```

Isn't 16 supposed to be:

```
00000000000000000000000000010000
```

So ~16 is supposed to be:

```
11111111111111111111111111101111
```

Why i'm not getting what i expected and why the result is negative?

This is what i'm trying to do:

I have a number for exemple 27 which is:

```
00000000000000000000000000011011
```

And want to check every bit if it's 1 or 0.

So i need to get for exemple this value

```
11111111111111111111111111110111
```

The use second one to check if the 3rd bit of the first is set to 1.

Comment: What *are* you getting?

Comment: What result are you getting and do you expect to get?

Comment: See [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). Try again with unsigned integers.

Comment: @chris i'm getting -17

Comment: @rullof, That's correct for most signed integer implementations (and by most, I mean like nearly all of them).

Comment: in order to get what you are expecting to get you should use unsigned int.

Comment: C/c++ doesn't have any support for binary numbers like that - your extra examples don't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And want to check every bit if it's 1 or 0.

To check an individual bit, you don't NOT the number, you AND it with an appropriate bit mask:

```
if ((x & 1) != 0) ... // bit 0 is 1
if ((x & 2) != 0) ... // bit 1 is 1
if ((x & 4) != 0) ... // bit 2 is 1
if ((x & 8) != 0) ... // bit 3 is 1
...
if ((x & (1 << n)) != 0) ... // bit n is 1
...
if ((x & 0x80000000) != 0) ... // bit 31 is 1
```

Answer (score 5):

Although there are pedantic points which can be made about compiler behaviour, the simple answer is that a `signed int` with the top bit set is a negative number.

So if you do something which sets the top bit of an `int` (a signed int, not an unsigned one), then ask the tools/library to show you the value of that `int`, you'll see a negative number.

This is not a universal truth, but it's a good approximation to it for most modern systems.

Note that it's `printf` which is making the representation here - because `%d` formats numbers as signed. `%u` may give the result you're expecting.  Just changing the types of the variables won't be enough, because `printf` doesn't know anything about the types of its arguments.

I would say that as a general rule of thumb, if you're doing bit-twiddling, then use `unsigned int`s and display them in hexadecimal. Life will be simpler that way, and it most generally fits with the intent. (Fancy accelerated maths tricks are an obvious exception)

Comment: Your edit makes no sense, as the compiler will see those numbers as huge decimal numbers, not binary.

Comment: Not it has a sense (check it)

Answer (score 1):

In two-complement arithmetic to get a reverse number (for example for value 16 to get value -16) you need reverse each bit and add 1.

In your example, to get -16 from 16 that is represented as

```
00000000000000000000000000010000
```

you need reverse each bit. You will get

```
11111111111111111111111111101111
```

Now you must add 1 and you will get

```
11111111111111111111111111110000
```

As you can see if you add these two values, you will get 0. It proves that you did all correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get ones' complement of a number, you need to put that number into an unsigned variable and show it as so.
In C it would be:

```
unsigned int x = ~16;
printf("%u\n", x);
```

and you will get `4294967279`. 
But if you are just trying to get the negative number of a certain one, put the - operator before it.

EDIT: To check whether a bit is 0 or 1, you have to use the bitwise AND.